# Switch between Kafka topics

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, apache-kafka-streams

I have a stream of events coming to my microservices from two different topics. Let's say topic A and topic B. Topic B stream comes usually during the night for a few minutes and topic A stream comes throughout the day. I want to prioritize topic B and somehow pause topic A as soon as topic B emits the first event. Though I can dynamically pause and restart the topic but looking for a better solution then pause and restart.

Comment: Can you share some details on how you consume? Do you have one consumer subscribed to multiple topics or two consumers within the same application subscribed to one topic each? Or are we even talking about separate microservices/applications?

Comment: @kopaka - Different microservice